# Is my laptop processor 64bit?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, cpu, operating-systems, 32-bit

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y510. I have always used 32bit OS in it. Yesterday I came across [this](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-ideapad-y510/4507-3121_7-32815684.html) detail of my laptop and it says processor of my laptop is 64bit (hope I have not misinterpret anything) so I did some google and I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37159/is-my-processor-64-or-32-bit) question. As I have Ubuntu installed I tried command in last answer (i.e `lscpu`) and output was same with some differences. My main concern are first two lines of output i.e.

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

My question is does my CPU support 64bit OS? As per [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/laptops-netbooks-minibooks/189753-so-do-i-have-32-bit-64-bit-system.html) link I think yes.

If yes then shouldn't be the output of `lscpu` be like samothing as below as far as I know i686 stands for 32bit. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
Architecture:          AMD64
CPU op-mode(s):        64-bit
```

Comment: Of course, you could have just downloaded a 64-bit "live" CD, and just tried... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does support 64bit OS.

It has two entries because on 64-bit processor you can install both 64 and 32 bit ubuntu.

Comment: thanx for clarifying the two entries meaning.

Comment: Do all 64-bit processors run 32-bit Ubuntu? E.g. [IA-64 Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium)? SPARC64? PA-RISC? s/64-bit/x86-64/

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick it is actually answered in the itanium wiki article you linked :) You CAN run 32 bit ubuntu on those, but they will be painfully slow.

Answer (score 2):

To know if the installed Ubuntu is of 32 or 64 bits:

- `getconf LONG_BIT`
- `uname -m`

If it shows i686 or i386 it means 32-bits.
If it shows x86_64 it means 64-bits.

If the CPU is 32 bit, Ubuntu must also be 32-bit.
If the CPU is 64 bit it can work with 64- or 32-bit OSes. We can choose to install 32- or 64-bit Ubuntu.

To know if the CPU is of 32 or 64 bits:

- `grep -w lm /proc/cpuinfo`

  - If we see lm in red, the CPU supports 64 bit. Otherwise it is 32 bits.
- `sudo lshw | grep “description: CPU” -A 12 | grep width`

  - It says clearly what we want to know.

Answer (score 1):

The output you saw from `lscpu` means your processor (Google says it has an Intel Core 2 Duo) is capable of 32-bit and 64-bit, but that you are currently running a 32-bit operating system.

The output from a 64-bit operating system is:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

You should be fine to install a 64-bit operating system if you wish.